# Extracting Path from OpenFileDialog path/filename

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, path

I'm writing a little utility that starts with selecting a file, and then I need to select a folder. I'd like to default the folder to where the selected file was.

`OpenFileDialog.FileName` returns the **full path & filename** - what I want is to obtain just the **path portion (sans filename)**, so I can use that as the initial **selected folder**.

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofd;
    private System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog fbd;
    ...
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string sourceFile = ofd.FileName;
        string sourceFolder = ???;
    }
    ...
    fbd.SelectedPath = sourceFolder; // set initial fbd.ShowDialog() folder
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       ...
    }
```

Are there any .NET methods to do this, or do I need to use `regex, split, trim,` etc??

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class from [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx). It contains useful calls for manipulating file paths, including [`GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) which does what you want, returning the directory portion of the file path.

Usage is simple.

```
string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
```

Comment: Thanks - it had to be a simple answer.

Note to self: coding after midnight is not recommended. Reading more than just the method prototype also helps, as the VS documentation lists this as public static string GetDirectoryName(string path) & I misinterpreted the parameter.

Answer (score 32):

how about this:

```
string fullPath = ofd.FileName;
string fileName = ofd.SafeFileName;
string path = fullPath.Replace(fileName, "");
```

Answer (score 18):

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    strfilename = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

Comment: Does initial directory change when the user selects a file? If not, then this approach would cause a problem when the user changes directory. 
Also, I don't think he wanted the `FileName` as part of his `sourceFolder`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use FolderBrowserDialog instead of FileDialog and get the path from the OK result.

```
FolderBrowserDialog browser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
string tempPath ="";

if (browser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  tempPath  = browser.SelectedPath; // prints path
}
```

Comment: So choose the file first and then navigate to it again and choose the folder??

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple way to do It !

```
string fullPath =openFileDialog1.FileName;
string directory;
directory = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf('\\'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This was all I needed for the full path to a file

```
@openFileDialog1.FileName
```