# How to show full file path in TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I have a FileDialog...

```
    string fileData = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

...and a TextBox1. How to see the full path of the opened file in the TextBox1?

Solution:

```
        textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}", openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: as I know it should be full path of the file. Can you describe in details?

`if (this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }`

Comment: horrible mess in this question, requirements are not clear and no real useful code sample, then question was edited with solution which is wrong because initially there was no openFileDialog2 and anyway answers below already said how to do it, string.format above is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below code.

```
TextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}",
    Path.GetDirectoryName(fileData),openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: If OP wants the filename included in the full path, this won't do it for him.

Comment: You right, i have modified the code, this should do it.

    TextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}",Path.GetDirectoryName(fileData),openFileDialog1.FileName);

Comment: Correct way - textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0}", openFileDialog2.FileName);

Comment: the usage of String.Format with only {0} is useless !!

Answer (score 6):

using `TextBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;`

Answer (score 2):

this is the best code it works 100% for me :

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "PDF Files(*.pdf)|*.pdf|WORD Files(*.doc;*.docx)|*.doc;*.docx|EXCEL Files(*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xls;*.xlt)|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xls;*.xlt|Image Files(*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpeg|All Files|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = ofd.FileName.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = path;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
TextBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

if does not work, please refine your question telling exactly what you need to retrieve and giving examples.

you might want to check this one as well:

[Extracting Path from OpenFileDialog path/filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439007/extracting-path-from-openfiledialog-path-filename)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `TextBox1.Text = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;` depending upon when you want to access the information.

Comment: OP appears to be using `OpenFileDialog`, not `FileUpload`.  Two different things :)

Comment: Ah crap, thanks for that.  I was in a sleep-deprived haze at the tiem.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring variable, try this:

```
String filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
textbox1.Text = filePath;
```