# Save/Upload Image To Database Using Its Path

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm want to save an image to a sql server DB by using it's path, that i don't want to save the image it self i just want when i upload an image to my form and when i click in a button this button upload the image to the application folder then save the path of this picture to the databasen, How can I do that ?

2 - how can i add this picture to a dataGridView ?

**NOTE : I'm using C# as a programming language.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the image file path can be done using OpenFileDialog.
 This answer can help you getting file path [Extracting Path from OpenFileDialog path/filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439007/extracting-path-from-openfiledialog-path-filename)

1) You can copy them using `File.Copy(path, path2)` function to your app directory : 

`string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`
2) You need to use Bitmap to get your image loaded from its file path :

```
Bitmap myBmp = Bitmap.FromFile("path here");
```

And then you can add it to a `DataGridView` assuming that contains `DataGridViewImageColumn`

```
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(<column1 value>, <column2 value>, myBmp, <column3 value>, <column4 value>);
```