# Get Selected Files Paths

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to get the selected files path, from this list, i get those files by odf.SafeFileNames, is there a way to get those files paths??
here is my code

```
        ofd.Title = "=SE= File Selector v.01";

        ofd.Multiselect = true;


        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            fileNames = ofd.SafeFileNames;



        }

        foreach (string FileName in fileNames)
        {

                Console.WriteLine(FileName + ":  " + filepath);


        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting Path from OpenFileDialog path/filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439007/extracting-path-from-openfiledialog-path-filename)

Comment: I am surprised you found `SafeFileNames` before `FileNames`.

Comment: i was trying to get names and then paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SafeFileNames` returns only file name and his extension
Use [FileNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames?view=netframework-4.8) instead to return full paths

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     fileNames = ofd.FileNames;
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderCastellanos glad that it can help you