# c# get Image directory path after selecting image on open file dialog

Tags: c#

is there a way to get the image directory path after selecting in file dialog

example `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\IMG\pix200.jpg`

i have a code that will open file dialog then after selecting Image and displaying Image in PictureBox
i need to get the image location or path directory as i said earlier

```
private void student_Edit_PictureBox_Front_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFD.Filter = "Bitmaps|*.bmp|jpeg|*.jpg";

        if (openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            student_Picture_Edit.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(openFD.FileName);
            student_Edit_PictureBox_Front.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(openFD.FileName);

            //I want to get the directory path Picturebox.Imagelocation is not working for me
        }
    }
```

is there a solution for this?

Comment: This should solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439007/extracting-path-from-openfiledialog-path-filename

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting Path from OpenFileDialog path/filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439007/extracting-path-from-openfiledialog-path-filename)

Comment: The PictureBox will not know which path the image came from; so you need to store it when loading.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make use of the `Path.GetDirectoryName` method.
Example:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFD.FileName);
```