# how can I get Image address or image URL while selecting an image using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, openfiledialog

I am creating a desktop application using C# in visual studio. The thing I want is that, how can I get file address of selected file, which is selected using "OpenFileDialog". i.e; if the selected file is an Image, I didn't want to store whole image in database I want to store its address only, so how can I get the address of image? is any body can help me with this?

Comment: Well it is a simple google search actually.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59140175/c-sharp-get-image-directory-path-after-selecting-image-on-open-file-dialog

Comment: after filedialog.show you can get the path of selected file 
string filepath= Path.GetDirectoryName(FileDialog1.FileName);